# Rolled over with lots of work?

Tags: idioms, expressions

I got an email from someone and he said he replied to the email because...

> I got rolled over with lots of work.

I searched for it on Google and dictionaries but could not find a suitable definition that seems suitable for this context. I assume this is sort of like 'swamped by'. Is it correct?

Comment: It could be the latest slang, but it is not a commonly used expression, AFAIK. As you state, from context, "swamped" or "inundated" seem appropriate.

Comment: Not an expression I've heard. DrMoishe Pippik's suggestions are good. I also wonder if it could be a mistake for "bowled over."

Comment: @Katy If it's the misspelling of "bowled over", is that roughly translated into "I got struck by lots of work"?

Comment: ["steamrolled"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steamroller) seems it could be the intended meaning.